# Unity Animation layers are delaying to start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game, and for that I have a few animations and states as follows:
[image]

Since I want to create a few different sprites as children of the main one, to eventually use as equipment, I have the following structure:

[image]

For each of these objects, I have created a few animations:

[image] [image] [image]

Then, besides the base layer, I have made others to match each of the game objects:

[image]

Each of these layers have a weight of 1 and sync with the base layer:

[image]

Then each of the states that have an animation in base have the same corresponding animation in their respective layers:

[image] [image]

However, when I run the game mode, I noticed that all of the animations delay when starting the jump (Jumping), and the tunic animation for falling is transparent for some reason:

[image]

I tried deleting the falling-tunic animation to see if redoing it fixes any errors I may have had, but it's the same. Is it possible that this is a performance error, or do I have a better way to confirm if there are different settings in the Falling state that I can't figure out by ensuring all values are correct?

Please let me know if anyone is aware of what I may be doing wrong

Comment: Might be the transition time? There's the fade in/out times that you can configure if you press on the white arrows between states.

Comment: I've looked at the transition times for the layers and they match the base layer. Is it possible this may be a bug?

Comment: I’ve removed transition times from `Idle` to `Jumping` and it fixed the delay. But I might have to try something different for the disappearing tunic (from `Jumped` to `Falling`)